# ClientError: Unable to parse csv: rows 1-1000, file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I've looked at the other answers to this issue and none of them are helping me. I am trying to run a simple random cut forest algorithm. I have a small data set of IPs which have been stripped down to only have numbers. I still get this error. It only has one column of these numbers. The CSV looks like this:

176162144

176862141

176762141

176761141

176562141

Comment: What is the code you're using to ingest the CSV data?

Comment: I'm not using any code outside of the AWS provided algorithm for random cut forest.

Comment: @Zach has your problem been solved? How are you invoking SageMaker? Are you using the AWS console, Boto, the SageMaker Python SDK RandomCutForest estimator?

Comment: @julitopower Yes! Before I converted the data to the numpy array, I made sure to cast the data as int and it worked. At some point the data was being calculated as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was utilizing the sample notebook Julien Simon mentioned earlier, but at some point the data was ending up as strings! The funny thing about RCF algorithms is they have to run on integer data. 
What I did is I made sure to cast the array as an int array as a double check and vallah! It worked. I am at loss over how the data ended up in a string format but alas, that was the issue. Simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this sample notebook, and tried using it with your own data?
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/random_cut_forest/random_cut_forest.ipynb

In a nutshell, it reads the CSV file with Pandas and trains the model like this:

```
rcf = RandomCutForest(role=execution_role,
                      train_instance_count=1,
                      train_instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                      data_location='s3://{}/{}/'.format(bucket, prefix),
                      output_path='s3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix),
                      num_samples_per_tree=512,
                      num_trees=50)

# automatically upload the training data to S3 and run the training job
rcf.fit(rcf.record_set(taxi_data.value.as_matrix().reshape(-1,1)))
```

You didn't say what your use case was, but as you're working with IP addresses, you may find the IP Insights built-in algorithm useful too: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ip-insights.html